# Powershell - Get user properties for a given OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to obtain users information (account, email, name, location, OU) for all the users within a given OU. I tried following but it does not give me anything. Any idea why?

```
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {OU -like "northwest-academy"}
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {OU -like "northwest-academy"} -Properties * | select e
mailaddress
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Filter {OU -like "northwest-academy} -Properties * | select e
mailaddress.emailaddress
PS C:\> $test = Get-ADUser -Filter {OU -like "northwest-academy} -Properties * |
select emailaddress.emailaddress
PS C:\> write-host $test

PS C:\> $test = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -like "smith"} -Properties * |
select emailaddress
PS C:\> write-host $test

PS C:\> $test = Get-ADUser -Filter {OU -like "northwest-academy} -Properties Emai
lAddress
PS C:\> $test.EmailAddress
PS C:\>
```

Comment: How are you determining your filter properties? `ADUser` has no "OU" property.

Answer (score 0):

`OU` isn't a property of an LDAP user account.  Try `Get-ADUser -Identity '$YourUserName' -Properties *` to get a list of valid properties.

The filter `{EmailAddress -like "smith"}` contains no wildcards so will not include partial matches.   Try `{EmailAddress -like "*smith*"}`.

Comment: So is there a way to get all the users for a given OU? Also, the script worked for email after I added wildcard.

Comment: Try the `-SearchBase` option with the full distinguished name of the OU.  If you don't want child OUs of the SearchBase, specify `-SearchScope Base`.  This is all in the [help file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This script worked..But I noticed that OU line up is case sensitive or something. So first I had to get the correct ou for that special group by fetching a user from that OU. For example,

```
PS C:\> $test = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -like "*Stanley*"} -Properties EmailAddress
PS C:\> write-host $test
PS C:\> $OU = "ou=specialusers,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"



Get-ADUser -searchbase $OU -filter * -Properties Department | Select-Object name, department > c:\temp\myfile.csv
```